# Failed to load resource: net::ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED, Error after deploy

Tags: node.js, reactjs

I developed a website using react and node.js, and my team deploy it on the server, the problem is when we try to use the website using the new domain or IP address it gives us this error:
[image]

Although it works fine in the localhost:3000 in the server, can you please give me the hints to solve this

Comment: Did you try with curl? Did you check there is not a firewall?

Comment: Actually, if I remember correctly the server deployed it has a firewall and security, maybe that is the case, it didn't work with other browsers.

Answer (score 0):

I also faced the same issue because of not updating
`backend URL` so make sure to check the backend URL in the frontend. If you host any cloud-like Heroku then include on `.env`

In your case, there might be some other reason as well.

Answer (score 0):

If app is functional in localhost:3000 (react's default host number)

and if you are using axios to fetch data from backend, then you should not hard code the URL like this:

NOTE: 3001 is the port number for my express server

```
    axios.post("http://localhost:3001/Signup",values)
    .then(res =>{
        console.log(res)
        navigate("/")
    })
    .catch(err => console.log(err))
```

change the URL to:

```
     axios.post(`http://localhost:${process.env.PORT || 3001}/Signup`,values)
    .then(res =>{
        console.log(res)
        navigate("/")
    })
    .catch(err => console.log(err))
```

this is because cloud platform service like Heroku cannot read port number 3001 hence we use process.env.PORT.

also in your express server ensure that your app is listening to  process.env.PORT not just 3001:

```
    const PORT = process.env.PORT || 3001;

    app.listen(PORT, () =>{
    console.log(`listening to ${PORT}`)
    }
```